# How to do a Local Communication between Console and Web application

Tags: c#, .net, forms, web, communication

I'm trying to send Data from a console application to a web application locally + I want to active the search function in the webapplication by calling : pressing Enter event :
[image]

this one represents the console application which will send the Part's ID when we press on SEND button;
[image]
this image represents my webapplication which is the destination of my Part's ID.

I want from the SEND button to do :

- Copy the Part's ID
- Send it to the webapplication "
- start the Enter event : to launch the searching ( Enter Key)

I tried to do the Copy function :

```
  private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

and it works , but when i came to the paste phase ( get ) i  couldn't figure out how to specify the correct direction ( Webapplication )  in my console application + i didn't figure out how to launch the Enter event Key after pasting in the Webapplication in order to launch the searching phase of my part.

**Remark : I want my connexion to be local that's why i didn't use WebAPI in order to connect.**

Any help please ?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `WebAPI` is just a template. You can add controllers to your web app, and that's probably what you need to do here. To communicate with your web app, you'll need an endpoint that you can call and pass the data. It doesn't matter if it's local or not.

Comment: If I'm gonna use a webAPI, the data will be transfered to all the client of my webapplication, but I only need to send it to the current client ( web application ) on the same machine with my console application